# definition of the hyperbolic space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In Jurgen Jost's book, there is an example about Hyperbolic space in Chapter 1.The author mentions that we can equip $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ with an inner product
$\langle x,y\rangle=x^1y^1+\cdots + x^ny^n-x^{n+1}y^{n+1}$,where $x=(x^1,\cdots, x^{n+1}),y=(y^1,\cdots, y^{n+1})$.

According to the definition of inner product,the following property should be satisfied:$\langle x,x\rangle\geq 0$,but the inner product defined above does not have positivity.

Comment: Correct. It is not like the usual inner-product, it can take negative values. It is just a symmetric bilinear form.

Comment: @ParthivBasu This difference of definitions/ naming conventions is all there is to this question. Can you write up your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a bilinear form is symmetric and non-degenerate, but not necessarily positive-definite, we can say that we have just a scalar product, instead of an inner product. The thing is that Minkowski space $(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_L)$, where $$\langle x,y\rangle_L =x^1y^1+\cdots +x^ny^n-x^{n+1}y^{n+1},$$is not an Euclidean vector space, as $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_L$ is not positive-definite. However, you can still have subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ for which the restriction of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_L$ is positive-definite. This is the case for the tangent spaces of the hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\mid \langle x,x\rangle_L=-1\}$, given by $T_x\mathbb{H}^n = x^\perp$, where $\perp$ is taken with respect to $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_L$. It is a general fact for spaces with Lorentzian scalar products that the orthogonal complement of a timelike vector is a spacelike subspace. The first section of [my notes about this topic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.01710) might be helpful.

Comment: That general fact is also nicely represented by the reality that we cannot ever "see" the present of anything that is removed from us in space... nor can it "see" our present.

Comment: I am still confused about the statement:"you can still have subspaces of Rn+1for which the restriction of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_L$ is positive definite.Would you mind interpreting it in details?

Comment: Ok, for example $\mathbb{R}e_1$, where $e_1$ is the first vector in the standard basis. Or, if take any collection of orthogonal vectors $(u_1,\ldots, u_k)$ for which $\langle u_i,u_i\rangle > 0$, then their span also has this property (we call those subspaces "spacelike" -- then I'm saying that the span of orthogonal spacelike vectors is again spacelike).

Comment: What I mean is that you can have that $\langle w,w\rangle_L > 0$ for every $w \in W \setminus \{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, for some subspaces $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.